# Two queries returning different results when they should be equivalent?

Tags: sql, inner-join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Our dataset is fundamentally joining a set of dates (weeks from the current week into the past) to a set of sections based on whether those sections started on or before and ended on or after that week. While originally this query gave us the results we expected, this week it began providing us incorrect results. After a bunch of tinkering, we discovered that if we changed the query to a `LEFT JOIN` and then filtered the query using a `WHERE` clause, it gave us correct results again.

What's the difference? Why does one work and the other doesn't? (**Bonus points:** why did the original query work for weeks before suddenly experiencing this error?) Performing the same inner join on Redshift delivers correct results, so it seems to be a Snowflake nuance that we don't understand.

**Original query:**

```
WITH week_list AS
(
    SELECT DATEADD(week, -4, DATE_TRUNC(week, CURRENT_DATE())) AS week_value

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEADD(week, 1, week_value)
    FROM week_list
    WHERE DATEADD(week, 1, week_value) < CURRENT_DATE()
),
active_sections_per_week AS
(
    SELECT 
        wl.week_value, s.id section_id
    FROM week_list wl
    JOIN schema.sections s ON wl.week_value >= DATE_TRUNC(week, s.starts_at)
                           AND wl.week_value <= DATE_TRUNC(week, s.ends_at)
)
SELECT 
    aspw.week_value,
    COUNT(DISTINCT aspw.section_id) count_sections
FROM 
    active_sections_per_week aspw
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

**Results:** One row, dated 2019-12-30 (4 weeks ago). No data for the past three weeks.

Note: If you adjust the `DATEADD` in the first CTE, whatever is the first date returned will always seem to join successfully. This behavior started only within the last week--previously, this query provided the expected number of rows (in other words, the number of weeks specified in that first `DATEADD`).

**"Fixed" query:**

```
WITH week_list AS
(
    SELECT DATEADD(week, -4, DATE_TRUNC(week, CURRENT_DATE())) AS week_value

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEADD(week, 1, week_value)
    FROM week_list
    WHERE DATEADD(week, 1, week_value) < CURRENT_DATE()
),
active_sections_per_week AS
(
    SELECT wl.week_value, s.id section_id
    FROM week_list wl
    LEFT JOIN schema.sections s ON wl.week_value >= DATE_TRUNC(week, s.starts_at)
                                AND wl.week_value <= DATE_TRUNC(week, s.ends_at)
    WHERE s.id IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT aspw.week_value, COUNT(DISTINCT aspw.section_id) count_sections
FROM active_sections_per_week aspw
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

**Results:** returns four rows, weeks dated 2019-12-30 to 2020-01-20, with appropriate section counts.

Comment: This is likely a silly question, but do you have a table called `week_list` as well as a CTE with the same name?

Comment: Just for checking if view merging is happening what would happen in the original query if you were to add "WHERE 1=1" in the active_sections_per_week

Comment: Great question @MikeWalton! I do not have a separate table with the same name, `week_list` here is always referring to the CTE.

Comment: Thanks @GeorgeJoseph for the suggestion! I tried adding `WHERE 1=1` in the `active_sections_per_week` CTE, but the results are the same (only one week is returned).

Comment: any luck if you try WHERE CURRENT_DATE() = CURRENT_DATE()

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion--unfortunately, no luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all of the feedback! The good news is you all helped me get to a solution that I think I am satisfied with. I have also followed up with Snowflake so they can investigate this behavior and see if it was user error on my part due to not understanding how recursive CTEs process, or whether it is possibly a bug introduced in a recent release.

Here's what I found: while recursion works for the use case I was applying it to (generating a list of dates based on `CURRENT_DATE`), it is not strictly necessary. Since we want a list of dates, I could just as easily generate a table and use the row numbers to perform the `DATEADD` adjustments.

It looks like this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(week, '-' || ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NULL), 
               DATEADD(week, 1, DATE_TRUNC(week, CURRENT_DATE()))) AS week_value
FROM table (generator(rowcount => 200))
```

One of the big benefits to this approach is I am no longer limited by the `MAX_RECURSIONS` setting in Snowflake (which is set to 100 by default). Since I am using this data to create graphs of activity over time, having 200 values gives me more than three years of history rather than just shy of 2 years of history. I also don't have to contact my Snowflake rep if I want to expand it.

Changing the `week_list` CTE to this non-recursive approach seems to fix whatever issue was causing the `INNER JOIN` to perform incorrectly. We still don't understand why the recursive CTE seemed to work for several weeks and then suddenly started misbehaving, but if Snowflake can shed light on that via our support ticket, I will double back here to provide an update. Thank you all for your help and guidance!

Comment: Ah, it's funny you used a generator, as that is what we use, but I simplified it, as your example had 4, and constant values works just as well there..,  but great to see you found a more useful to you solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is a recursive CTE on "week_list". [Redshift does not support recursive CTEs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-features.html).

[Snowflake does support recursive CTEs](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/queries-cte.html#recursive-cte-considerations), which would explain the difference in behavior.

It's hard to test this without the underlying data. If you're getting correct results in Redshift, then chances are you do not need or want a recursive CTE. You can modify it so that "week_list" does not reference itself.

As for why it worked before, it's likely the table state and recursive CTE worked only under special cases. When CURRENT_DATE() advanced, it took it out of that special case. Also, the inner join and left outer join where s.id IS NOT NULL ***would*** be equivalent if not in a recursive CTE.

You can read more about recursive CTEs here:

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/queries-cte.html#recursive-ctes-and-hierarchical-data

Comment: Thank you for the notes! I apologize I was not clearer in my original post--although this query "works" in Redshift, it requires a lot of small syntactical changes as well as one major change: the CTE has to be modified so it creates a list of dates (which, as you said, is different since Redshift does not support this kind of recursion). That part of the query I changed to be something like:

`SELECT DATEADD('week', -n, DATE_TRUNC('week', CURRENT_DATE)) AS week_value
    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS n FROM stl_scan LIMIT 4) n
    ORDER BY week_value DESC`

Comment: I will check out the link you provided (thank you!) but do you offhand have reason to think that it is the recursive CTE specifically that is causing the issue? I would really love to understand the issue as there are other inner joins involved in this query (it is much longer and more complex than the snippet provided, the snippet just gets to the heart of what's broken) and I'm concerned other joins could suddenly "break" because I haven't understood what the issue was in the first place.

Comment: Hi Vic. Without the underlying data to test it, the recursion on the CTE is an educated guess on why it behaves differently with an inner join vs a left join with the where clause. Reading some of the comments it appears you have a case open with Support. I think it's a great idea to have them take a look and with access to the whole situation can make a determination.

Answer (score 1):

the recursive CTE can be avoided **if** the -4 weeks is a constant with this code:

```
WITH week_list AS (
    SELECT DATEADD(week, column1, DATE_TRUNC(week, CURRENT_DATE())) 
    FROM VALUES (-4),(-3),(-2),(-1),(0)
)
```

with the `JOIN` snowflake will move the filters higher in the execution stack, and you might have found a bug. Where-as with the `LEFT JOIN` (even though it has a equivalent `WHERE` clause it most likely avoiding the aggressive broken optimization.

There was a software release last night for us, but we are on an Enterprise account so you might have been upgrade 2 days prior. This release had a number of bugs that impacted us, we had it rolled back (for us)

Comment: Fascinating! I guess I need to stay aware of releases--I typically leave that to my data engineering team and our Snowflake reps. This is super helpful, I will follow up with that group to see if this is indeed a bug. Thank you very much!

Comment: Well if you process has not changed, and there is no difference in the data, the only option left is the engine has changed and they release frequently, and a couple of time a year, release are at least "not good for our use case" and other time stuff get faster like magic..

Comment: Thanks, makes sense! I also just posted an answer that is inspired by your suggestion to get rid of the recursive CTE. It seems to have done the trick! Thanks again!